# Boot2Docker: how to access container with Bridged Networking

Tags: networking, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am running Boot2Docker in Virtual Box on Windows, using VB bridged networking. The IP address of my PC (192.168.2.2) and of the VM (192.168.2.30) is determined by the DHCP server.

I have configured the docker bridge as follows:

File /var/lib/boot2docker/profile:
EXTRA_ARGS='--bip=192.168.2.192/25 --fixed-cidr=192.168.2.224/27'

From my Windows PC I can successfully ping the folloing IP addresses:
192.168.2.30   (ip address of eth1 in the Docker Host)
192.168.2.192  (ip address of docker0)

However I cannot ping any container that I start. E.g. for container IP 192.168.2.226,
I get a reply from 192.168.2.2 (my PC address) that the Desitination Host is unreachable.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run and route containers on the same network interface that boot2docker uses for host to VM communication, is this correct?

Comment: I want to have the containers "visible" outside the Docker Host.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the meantime:

On Windows 7, from an elevated cmd shell do:
route add 192.168.2.224/27 192.168.2.30

This way the IP packets find their way to the containers!